# Is there a way to change the caption of a button based on a grid row being selected?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'd like to change the caption of a PXAction button (placed in the grid's action bar) based on which row is highlighted / selected - and using one of the field's values to set that caption.  The Grid's RowSelected event doesn't fire when a row is actually selected, so that won't work.

Is there another way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this with javascript.  However, an alternative is to use different buttons/actions and leverage a state field to enable/disable the various buttons.

If you are unfamiliar with this methodology, you can check PO Link on the SO301000 screen under the Details tab within the ActionBar-CustomItems section.

Set the DependsOnGrid of the grid's ID and the StateColumn to a field in the DAC that you set based on whether you want that action to be enabled or disabled.

```
<px:PXToolBarButton Text="PO Link" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="IsPOLinkAllowed">
  <AutoCallBack Command="POSupplyOK" Target="ds" ></AutoCallBack>
</px:PXToolBarButton>
```

I suspect you already know this, but if you find a way to trigger the rename, the rename is completed pretty easily.

```
myAction.SetCaption("My New Button Label");
```